# Python convert two different lists to list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two different lists in Python:

```
a = ['john', 'doe', 'bruce']
b = [70, 90, 50]
```

Desired result:

```
result = [['john', 70], ['doe', 90], ['bruce', 50]]
```

How can I combine them?

Comment: Using the following `restult = list(zip(a,b))`

Comment: Then `[list(t) for t in zip(a,b)]` - I don't really see the point in expanding the tuples to `i,j` as done in the answer posted so far.

Comment: For completeness, there is also the `map` function - `list(map(list, zip(a,b)))` - although I guess that most will agree that the list comprehension is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Try simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = ['john', 'doe', 'bruce']
b = [70, 90, 50]

res = [list(tup) for tup in zip(a,b)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['john', 70], ['doe', 90], ['bruce', 50]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following :

```
a = ['john', 'doe', 'bruce']
b = [70, 90, 50]
c=[]
for j,i in enumerate(a):
    c.append([i,b[j]])
print(c)
```